# Reverse decimation

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d

I'm wondering if there's such a thing as reverse decimation for 3d graphics. I've seen this on pixel art, although not called that way, and can have very nice results.

Comment: Do you mean *mesh refinement*?

Comment: As far as I know, the opposite of decimation is interpolation.  Although I have no experience with 3D graphics.

Comment: For images, do you mean [super-resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution)? See a nice demo at http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SingleImageSR.html

Comment: You may be looking for the term "tesselate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was ATI's Truform.